# How to fix a boot loop caused by editing build.prop. and formatting /system)?

Tags: boot-loop

I by mistake edited my `build.prop` file 
it boot looped,  I then in recovery mode formatted every thing
even `/system`.

I downloaded stock ROM of INTEX AQUA POWER HD and tried to install it using sp flash tools but was unsuccessful. Then I used [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) to pull `build.prop` to edit and pulled it 
It was like a folder `build.prop` in which there was another folder `xbin` in which there was `su` file which wasn't the build.prop

How can I resolve this bootloop issue?

note: I have a mediatek device.

Answer (score 0):

Go to recovery and wipe everything

Install the zip file of the stock rom that you downloaded from within the recovery.

Wipe Dalvik and cache.

Reboot.

Make a backup next time before modifying anything.